# How to use the `Backbone.View.events` definition to listen for custom subview events?

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

Is it possible to use the `Backbone.View.events` definition to listen for custom subview events?

**Child definition**

All `click` events are cached and trigger my `clicked` function:

```
var Child = Backbone.View.extend({
    events : {
        'click' : 'clicked'
    },
    clicked: function() {
       alert('View was clicked');
       this.trigger("customEvent");  
    },
    render: function() {
      this.$el.html("<span>Click me</span>");
    }
});
```

**Parent definition**

Why don't `customEvent` events call my `action` function?

```
var Parent = Backbone.View.extend({
    events : {
        'customEvent' : 'action'
    },
    action : function() {
       alert('My sub view triggered a custom event');  
    },
    render : function() {
      var child = new Child();
      this.$el.append(child.el);
      child.render();
    }
});
```

Create and render parent

```
var parent = new Parent();
parent.$el.appendTo(document.body);
parent.render();
```

[**jsfiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/YLzUJ/)

I know that could use `listenTo` instead but using the events definition seems to be cleaner.

My intention is to build a sub view (e.g. a color picker) which triggers an event after it is done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quick Notes:-

- In events object of a view, we should not define custom events. For custom events we should do binding. Use either bind() method or listen to some event using on().
- If your subview's el element is inside your parent view's el, you can directly listen to events on child's el too provided you are not returning false from child's event handler.
  Take a look at this: [Code where parent view is listening event on element onside child view](http://jsbin.com/arafeh/1/edit)

If you want to use custom event only, You can see here [Your Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YLzUJ/1/)

```
var Child = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.parent = options.parent;
    },
    events : {
        'click' : 'clicked'
    },
    clicked: function() {
       alert('View was clicked');
       this.parent.trigger("customEvent");  
    },
    render: function() {
      this.$el.html("<span>Click me</span>");
    }
});

var Parent = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.on('customEvent', this.action);
    },
    action : function() {
       alert('My sub view triggered a custom event');  
    },
    render : function() {
      var child = new Child({parent: this});
      this.$el.append(child.el);
      child.render();
    }
});

var parent = new Parent();
parent.$el.appendTo(document.body);
parent.render();
```

Comment: What do you think about `this.$el.trigger("customEvent")`?

Comment: Once again, your el element is not listening to "customEvent" so this won't work too. Right ? Please take a look at JSbin code.

Comment: YES..good point. It is working because your parent view is listening to custom event on elements present inside el. I was talking about child view. This custom event won't be triggered inside childview because child view is not listening to it. But its not a good practice to mention your custom events inside events object. Prefer binding if you are comfortable.

Comment: See this http://jsfiddle.net/YLzUJ/3/
Now your child view is also listening to customEvent on el element So now it will trigger the handler.

Comment: My intention is to build a picker (e.g. a color picker) which triggers an event after it is done and allow the parent view to react on that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27716/discussion-between-blunderboy-and-jantimon)